# Excel file not genereted completly wiht PHP under Google Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, phpexcel

I'm generating an excel file from PHP with PHPExcel library and when it's filled with all the data it's is automaticaly downloaded, the problem is that chrome only shows column headers without data, meanwhile firefox downloads de file correctly.

my code is :

```
    <?php
    //Code pour les nouvelles demandes d'agréments

    //echo $_POST['sql'] . '\n\n\n';

    //IMPORTANT :  Il ne faut PAS inclure la connexion mais la mettre comme ci-dessous car bug connu avec PHPEXCEL (fichier gÈnÈrÈ via le navigateur inexploitable !!!!)
    try
    {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=qque', 'qqe', 'prive', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));

    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        print "Erreur !: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION))
    {
        session_start();
    }

    include 'PHPExcel.php';
    include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setTitle('Résultat filtre');


   $pharmaciens = $bdd->prepare($_POST['sql']);
   $pharmaciens->execute();

   $res = $pharmaciens->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            //print_r($res);

   $i = 2;
   $temp_nombre_jours = 0;
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'NOM');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'PRENOM');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'ADRESSE');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D1', 'CODE POSTAL');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E1', 'LOCALITE');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F1', 'PAYS');
   //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E1', 'ANNEE DEBUT AGREMENT');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G1', 'TELEPHONE');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H1', 'MAIL');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I1', 'DEBUT AGREMENT');

   //redimensionnement des colonnes afin d'avoir des colonnes en autosize
   for($col = 'A'; $col !== 'L'; $col++)
   {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getColumnDimension($col)
        ->setAutoSize(true);
    }

                foreach($res as $donnees)
                {
                                $styleArray = array('font' => array('bold' => true));

                                //je mets en gras le contenu de ces cellules
                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);

                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);

                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('K1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);

                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$i, $donnees->nom);
                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$i, $donnees->prenom);
                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$i, $donnees->adresse);

                                //pays
                                if(strtolower($donnees->pays) == "belgique")
                                {
                                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$i, $donnees->code_postal_be);
                                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$i, $donnees->libelle_be);
                                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$i, "BELGIQUE");    
                                }
                                elseif(strtolower($donnees->pays) == "france")
                                {
                                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$i, $donnees->code_postal_fr);
                                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$i, $donnees->libelle_fr);
                                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$i, "FRANCE");    
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$i, $donnees->code_postal_lux);
                                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$i, $donnees->libelle_lux);
                                                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$i, "LUXEMBOURG");    
                                }


                                 //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$i, $donnees->SUBSTR(date_debut, 1, 4));
                                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValueExplicit('G'.$i, $donnees->telephone, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
                                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H'.$i, $donnees->mail);
                                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I'.$i, $donnees->date_debut);


                                    $i = $i+1;
   }//fin du foreach

                try
    {
        $writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);


                                $writer->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));

                                echo 'Exportation OK, veuillez cliquer <a href="http://stageoff.ulb.ac.be/classes/Excel/Classes/filtre_generation_excel.xlsx"><img src="../../../images/excel.jpg" /></a> pour sauvegarder le document';
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        print "Erreur !: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }


?>
```

Comment: Unless you have special coding to check; then PHP doesn't care whether it's being called from Google Chrome, from Firefox, from IE, from Opera, from Safari.... but you're not sending any spreadsheet to the browser here; you're saving the spreadsheet file to the server disk, and providing a link too that file; so the browser itself is 100% irrelevant to creation of the file

Comment: Thank you Mark for your reply.  I don't find the solution of this issue.  I tried all... Maybe a special coding like you said...